# Attending 3 day conference but a tourist for 10 days

Tags: visas, schengen

I'm an Indian Citizen and I'm planning on attending a 3 day conference in Portugal, but spend another 10 days in Spain and Portugal as a tourist. Which visa type should I apply for - business or travel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application you just state that after the 3 days conference in Portugal (main purpose of visit) you would like to spend a further 10 days for tourism in Portugal and Spain.

A business visa (when needed) always includes a visitor visa. So if for a conference a business visa is required, just add the itinerary for the tourism portion in the application.

Comment: Do I have to apply for this Schengen Visa at the Portuguese Consulate? or can I apply in Spain?

I know it makes more sense to apply in the Portuguese consulate, but I'm getting a much earlier appointment in the Spanish Consulate.

Comment: @UtsavShah Yes, since Portugal is the country for the main purpose of your visit. Spain will probably refuse to accept your application due to this reason.